# Rindler decomposition using Euclidean path integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, qft-in-curved-spacetime, unruh-effect

In section 3.3 of Jerusalem Lectures on Black Holes and Quantum Information ([arXiv:1409.1231](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1231)), Daniel Harlow wants to calculate the following Euclidean path integral
$$\langle\phi |\Omega\rangle\propto\int_{\hat{\phi}(t_E=-\infty)=0}^{\hat{\phi}(t_E=0)=\phi} \mathcal{D}\hat{\phi}e^{-I_E}\tag{3.16}$$
He then says

> In understanding the entanglement of the vacuum however, it is more convenient to evaluate it in a way that continues to work when interactions are present. The method is shown in figure (8). It is based on the observation that the boost operator $K_x$ in the Euclidean plane generates rotations in the $xt_E$ plane, as can be seen from analytically continuing its action on $t$ and $x$. So instead of evaluating the path integral from $t_E = −\infty$ to $0$, we instead evaluate it along the angular direction over an angle $\pi$. **From the point of view of the path integral this is just a trivial change of variables**, but it makes clear that there is a nice alternative Hilbert space interpretation of the same path integral;
> $$
> \left\langle\phi_{L} \phi_{R} \mid \Omega\right\rangle \propto\left\langle\phi_{R}\left|e^{-\pi K_{R}} \Theta\right| \phi_{L}\right\rangle_{L},\tag{3.18}
> $$
> where $K_{R}$ is the **restriction** of $K_{x}$ **to the right Rindler wedge** and $\Theta$ is an antiunitary operator that exists in all quantum field theories and is usually called CPT. Its action on a Heisenberg picture scalar field is ${}^{15}$
> $$
> \Theta^{\dagger} \Phi(t, x, \vec{y}) \Theta=\Phi^{\dagger}(-t,-x, \vec{y})\tag{3.19}
> $$
> We can then evaluate (3.18) by inserting a complete set of $K_{R}$
> eigenstates:
> $$\langle \phi_L\phi_R|\Omega \rangle\propto \sum_{i}e^{-\pi\omega_i}\langle \phi_L|i^*\rangle_L\langle\phi_R|i\rangle_R $$
> [image]

---

1. What change of variable is going on here? From the above figure, I can see that as $K_{R}$ is the restriction of $K_{x}$ to the right Rindler wedge, if we apply $e^{-\pi K_{R}}$ the **right lower quadrant** in the Euclidean space **will become** the **left upper quadrant**. What exactly did he do in this step and why do we need to introduce the $CPT$ operator?
2. Also, why are the eigenvalues of $K_{R}$ energies ($\omega_i$)? The boost operator is not a hermitian operator (it is a unitary operator), then why will it have real eigenvalues (energies)?